# peewee update not workong

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to update the data in the table, but for some reason nothing comes out, what could this be related to?
Here is my code:

```
async def save_edit_payment_type(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()
    user_data = await state.get_data()
    callback_data_payment = callback_query.data
    await state.update_data(callback_data_payment=callback_data_payment)
    if callback_data_payment == 'cash':
        await callback_query.message.answer('Выберите тип:', reply_markup=keyboards.additional_data)
        await WaiteEditOrder.waiting_purchase_or_sale_data.set()
    else:
        order = Order.get(id=user_data["index"])
        order.update(
            payment_type=callback_data_payment,
            purchase_or_sale='',
            amount_to_be_paid=0,
        )
        order.save()
        await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely incorrect:

```
order = Order.get(id=user_data["index"])
order.update(
    payment_type=callback_data_payment,
    purchase_or_sale='',
    amount_to_be_paid=0,
)
order.save()
```

Please consult the documentation for very simple examples of how to update an object, but because it's SO, here's the solution:

```
order = Order.get(id=user_data["index"])
order.payment_type=callback_data_payment
order.purchase_or_sale=''
order.amount_to_be_paid=0
order.save()
```

Docs http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#storing-data